# For what values of $\ a $ $\ \dim(\ker T) \oplus \dim(\operatorname{Im}T) = \mathbf R^3 $

Tags: linear-algebra, linear-transformations

Let $\ A $ represent a transformation from $\ \mathbb R^3 \rightarrow \mathbb R^3 $

$$\ \begin{bmatrix} 1 & 1 & a+1 \\ 1 & a+1 & 1 \\ a+1 & 1 & 1 \end{bmatrix} | \  a \in \mathbf R$$

Find for which values of $\ a $ $\ \ker T \oplus \operatorname{Im}T = \mathbf R^3 $

Is it true that it is a direct sum whenever $\ T$ is isomorphism ?

Also is it true that $\ (\ker T) \oplus (\operatorname{Im}T) \not = \mathbf R^3 $ only if $\ \ker T \subseteq \operatorname{Im}T $ ?

Comment: What is a direct sum of dimensions?

Comment: Sorry, fixed...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. Yes, but that's not all the cases.
2. No. Consider nonzero $\mathcal T$ with $\mathcal T^2 = \mathcal O$, then $\mathrm {Im}(\mathcal  T) \subseteq \mathrm {Ker}(\mathcal T)$. In this case, $\mathrm {Ker}(\mathcal T) \subseteq \mathrm {Im}(\mathcal T)$ cannot happen according to the *nullity-rank theorem*.

Comment: Oh right.. whenever there's a $\ v \in R^3 $ such that $\ T(w) = v $ and $\ T(v) = 0 \rightarrow \operatorname{Im}T \subseteq KerT $ correct?

Comment: Right. But sorry, my counterexample seems problematic, let me check it.

Comment: Okay seems fine now.